# Replicate my Mouse config in command line

Tags: terminal, mouse, macos

How can I replicate my mouse config (in the images below) through command line?

[image]
[image]

Comment: which kind of mouse do you have? AppleBluetooth?

Comment: Apple Magic Mouse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like that should do it:

```
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist MouseOneFingerDoubleTapGesture -int 0
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist MouseTwoFingerDoubleTapGesture -int 3
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist MouseTwoFingerHorizSwipeGesture -int 2
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist MouseButtonMode -string TwoButton
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist com.apple.mouse.scaling -float 3
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist com.apple.swipescrolldirection -boolean NO
```

- `com.apple.swipescrolldirection -boolean NO` disables Scroll direction: natural
- `MouseButtonMode -string TwoButton` enables Secondary click right
- `MouseOneFingerDoubleTapGesture -int 0` disables Smart zoom
- `com.apple.mouse.scaling -float 3` enables fastest tracking
- `MouseTwoFingerHorizSwipeGesture -int 2` enables Swipe between pages with one finger and Swipe between full-screen apps with two fingers
- `MouseTwoFingerDoubleTapGesture -int 3` enables Mission Control